# How to use time variable instead of UNIX TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())

Tags: php, mysql, unix, timestamp

At the moment I have this code:

```
    $rawsql = "SELECT 
*
FROM 
    numbers n 
INNER JOIN 
    openings o ON n.id = o.branch_id AND o.dotw = DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE()) 
INNER JOIN 
    openings_times t ON o.id = t.opening_id
WHERE 
(
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) 
    BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' ', t.open)) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' ', t.close))
) 
AND 
(
    n.id = %d
);";
```

which is used to run an opening-times query. I have a variable $latest_ping, which basically contains the latest time that a user has 'pinged' the database.

If possible, I would like to replace the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP with this $latest_ping variable, because we want to use different timezones etc.

I have tried things like

UNIX_TIMESTAMP($latest_ping) and time($latest_ping) but they didn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should use a prepared statement and than pass the parameter. This is usually better than concatenate sql statement.

Comment: define "contains time", dude. Nobody knows what do you mean with this "time"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try with

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_format("$latest_ping", '%Y-%c-%d %k:%i:%s' ))
```

Edit : actually it is also not needed. Make sure the date is formated as it is used in mysql

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried that but it didn't work...I seem to have sussed it though (I think). I used $timestamp = strtotime($latest_ping); and then simply replaced the UNIX_TIMESTAMP code with '$timestamp and it seems to be working as I need it to. Not sure if this way is ideal but as long as it works!

Comment: use PHP date format function to properly format it. http://in2.php.net/manual/en/function.date-format.php